# Spring Prototype bean with different parameters

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I want to inject a prototype scoped bean into a singleton.  This prototype bean should only be created once for each Singleton it is injected in (which is the case by default as far as I understand).  However, I do want a slightly different bean each time, so I want to be able to annotate the injection point with a custom annotation which is used when constructing the prototype bean.

The problem is, how do I find out what annotations are on the injection point?

Here's some code to see what I want to achieve:

```
@Component
public class X {
    @Inject
    @CustomAnnotation("Hi")
    private PrototypeBean bean;
}
```

Where PrototypeBean is provided by a bean method:

```
@Bean
public PrototypeBean prototypeBean(CustomAnnotation customAnnotation) {
    return new PrototypeBean(customAnnotation);
}
```

The idea is here that everywhere this PrototypeBean is injected, a new instance is created which behaves slightly differently based on the value of CustomAnnotation.

I know you can do this using the ApplicationContext (well, passing extra parameters that is, not annotations), but I'd like to keep it light-weight with simple annotations.

Comment: It sounds like you really want a factory.

Comment: @Bean annotated methods are sort of the new factories, but I don't mind doing it differently as long as class X can be written to something close to the example

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you need is a custom [`BeanPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html). Section "3.2 Data Access" in this blog post, "[A Spring Custom Annotation for a Better DAO](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-annotation-bean-pre-processor)" looks very similar to what you're trying to do.